# Strange column width behavior when input inside

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with given problem:

html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><div>Data 1</div></td>
        <td ><div><input/></div></td>
        <td><div>Data 2</div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
th {
    width: 50px;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcdvpk1y/1/

The problem is that this example is shown differently in different browsers. On Chrome column withinput has independent computed width, but on IE and Edge width is taken from specified value.

I am eager to know cause of this different behaviour because it's simplified example of bigger problem, where I can't customize my code as I wish, has to know cause to apply the simplest solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added screenshots of the different renderings on each browser. Anyway, I couldn't understand the problem - you specified input width in percentage, not actual absolute value.

Comment: Browsers do not render the same way. If you want a consistent cross-browser layout then try using a CSS reset library like the one written by Eric Meyer or NormalizeCSS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have reset.css linked in your file?  That could cause strange behavior in sizing across different browsers.

Try linking this in an external stylesheet:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<div>` inside each `<td>`, you could get the correct appearance.

For fix it only with CSS (without change the markup), the following snippet should work.

```
td {
    width: 50px;
}

td div {
    width: inherit;
}

td div input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/d9fxu41z/